# ElGamal same private and random key attack

Tags: elgamal-encryption, elgamal-signature

I'm having difficulty understanding this.

Consider two messages are encrypted using the same cyclic group order $q$, generator $g$, private key $x$, and random parameter $y$.
The attacker knows a plaintext $m_1$ and its corresponding ciphertext $c_1=\left(r_1,s_1\right)$.

I was told that, under these circumstances, if an attacker **also** knows the ciphertext $c_2=\left(r_2,s_2\right)$ of another message $m_2$, they can recover $m_2$.

How is this possible? Wouldn't the attacker need to know $q$ and $g$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$q$ and $g$ are usually assumed to be public knowledge - they are known as public parameters (or are part of the users' public keys).

If the same random value $y$ is used for both messages, then $r_1 = r_2 = g^y$.

Then we know that $s_1 = (r_1^x) \cdot m_1$ and $s_2 = (r_1^x) \cdot m_2$.

Thus the attacker can compute $$m_2 = \frac{s_2}{s_1}m_1$$ in the group.

Comment: Ah thanks. If I had understood that *q* and *g* are considered public knowledge, this is exactly what I would have done.

Comment: What if we were to introduce modulo?

Comment: "In the group" means modulo the order of the group. E.g. the inversion of $s_1$ is done modulo $q$

Comment: I guess I'm not understanding. For example $m_1=s_1\times\left({r_1}^x\right)^{-1}\mod q$. How did you get $s_1=r_1\times m_1$ from that?

Comment: Sorry, I just forgot to write the power of $x$. Fixed :)

Comment: What about the inverse?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: $\left(r_1^x\right)^{-1}$

Comment: Yes, what about it? It's the same as what I wrote, but inverted. I'd encourage you to expand out the details if you're not sure, and see that it all cancels.