# ElGamal same private and random key attack

Tags: elgamal-encryption

I'm having difficulty understanding this.

Consider two messages are encrypted using the same cyclic group of order $q$, generator $g$, private key $x$, and random parameter $y$.
The attacker knows a plaintext $m_1$ and its corresponding ciphertext $c_1=(r_1,s_1)$.

I was told that, under these circumstances, if an attacker **also** knows the ciphertext $c_2=(r_2,s_2)$ of another message $m_2$, they can recover $m_2$.

How is this possible? Wouldn't the attacker need to know $q$ and $g$?

Comment: In ElGamal encryption, $g$ and $q$ are assumed public \[or/and part of the public key, which is public as it's name implies\]. I think the crux of the question is that it is assumed a _faulty_ implementation of [ElGamal encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ElGamal_encryption) using a fixed $y$. That question would be better if it contained the definition of ElGamal encryption used, which differs in notation from the one I linked \[which uses $(c_1,c_2)$ where the question uses $(r,s)$ \]. That definition will be necessary to answer this question. If it's homework, show what you tried.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ElGamal same private and random key attack](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/99887/elgamal-same-private-and-random-key-attack)

Comment: This is cross-posted with [math.se](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4439392/338051)

Answer (score 2):

> I was told that, under these circumstances, if an attacker also knows the ciphertext $c_2=(r_2,s_2)$ of another message $m_2$, they can recover $m_2$.

That's not right; just one plaintext/ciphertext pair doesn't allow decryption of unrelated ciphertexts.

If it did, ElGamal would be insecure; after all, anyone could encrypt a known plaintext with the public key, creating a known plaintext/ciphertext pair.  If that was enough to allow them to decrypt, anyone could decrypt.

Perhaps what was meant was that the second ciphertext was $(r_1, s_2)$ (alternatively, that $r_1 = r_2$); in that case, plaintext recovery is possible (and is not hard to work out - you might want to think this through).

One other thing:

> Wouldn't the attacker need to know $q$ and $g$?

Those are usually considered system parameters (along with the what the cyclic group is); it is assumed that the attacker knows them

Comment: Double-check my post. The attacker knows $m_1$, $c_1$, and $c_2$. And yes, the second ciphertext is $\left(r_1,s_2\right)$.

Comment: @PublicIP: I double-checked your question; I don't see where you mentioned that $r_1 = r_2$.  In any case, my statement that "that case is easy to solve" remains correct (and not that hard to figure out).  If you need a hint, well, write out the formula for $s_1, s_2$,,,